# cocoa Pod svn issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, svn, cocoapods

I have integrated cocoa pod in my project. The workspace was successfully created and all is fine. After that I committed the same to SVN. Now when someone else takes a checkout, they get the follwing error.

```
diff: /<path to cocoa pod>/Pods/../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /<path to cocoa pod>/Pods/Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your Cocoa Pods installation.
```

Also the workspace is also not created.

Comment: And when they run `pod install`?

Comment: @KeithSmiley The pod is already installed. INstalled the pod before checking out the code

Comment: @Droidme, you should do as keith smiley says, a simple pod install should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you little workaround here.

Before initial commit to SVN, ignore "**Pods**" folder in project files.

- Create new project
- terminal : **pod init**
- Add your dependencies to podfile
- terminal : **pod install**
- terminal : **svn propset svn:ignore Pods .** 
  // ignores Pods folder under project folder.
- Do your first commit to SVN
- terminal : **svn commit -m "FIRST COMMIT"**
- When others checkout project from SVN, they need to **pod install** once and ignore "**Pods**" folder.